# Is "bring in its wake a loss of jobs" correct?

Tags: syntax

> The spread of multinational products can often bring in its wake a
>   loss of jobs, as people turn to buying the new brand, perhaps thinking
>   it more glamorous.

Can you explain the structure of "its wake a loss of jobs"? It seems unordinary to me. Does not a comma missed after 'wake'?  (I know that wake means aftermath/backwash here)

Comment: It may be easier to understand if you reverse the phrases thus: _"The spread of multinational products can often bring a loss of jobs in its wake..."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thanks, Your order is what I expect. I do not remember any similar alternation similar to this. Is this specific to this phrase or it is a general rule?

Comment: The writer chose to place the adverbial preposition phrase immediately after the verb because it sounded better to him, I suppose. It's purely a stylistic choice, and not unusual in English. It could go nearly anywhere, e.g.: _"In its wake, the spread of multinational products can often bring a loss of jobs..."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As P.E.Dant has commented, you can reverse the phrases. To answer your followup question, yes, it is a general rule. You can usually put phrases in a sentence in different orders without changing the overall meaning.

The order of phrases in English usually has to do with what you want to emphasize. Typically, what comes first has the most emphasis, and what comes last has a secondary emphasis.

These sentences all have the same meaning, but with different emphasis on the ideas it contains:

> The order of phrases in English usually has to do with what you want to emphasize.
>   Usually, the order of phrases in English has to do with what you want to emphasize.
>   In English, the order of phrases usually has to do with what you want to emphasize.
>   What you want to emphasize is usually what the order of phrases has to do with in English.
>   What you want to emphasize, usually, is what in English the order of phrases has to do with.

You will note the addition of an extra *is what* in the last two sentences. This is optional in the word orders in which it's missing (as an editor, I would call this sentence awkward and change it, but it serves as an example):

> In English, what the order of phrases usually has to do with is what you want to emphasize.

As for when to use commas, it is to some extent a matter of style. [This](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/comma.html) is a good general guide.

Comment: Hey Bob, Many thanks for your all-inclusive answer.